# Mac OS X - Scripting mouse wheel scroll and mouse clicks

Tags: macos, mac, automation

On Mac OS X I would like to be able to press a key resulting in the mouse wheel scrolling a certain amount followed by a mouse click on a specifik point.

Are there any tools that can help me achieve that? Or maybe built in OS X features?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The built-in Automator appiication comes to my mind, thoguh it's a bit buggy (at least the "Watch me do" module which doesn't really do any good at recording mouse movement and clicks).

There's an open-source automation tool called [Sikuli](http://www.sikuli.org/).

You could also use [Keyboard Maestro](http://www.keyboardmaestro.com/) for that, but it costs $36 and does a lot of things, so it's an overkill.